# nginx server configuration to redirect all requests to ssl without subdomain

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

I want to redirect all requests to example.org. 
I created a configuration file as below. I can redirect the requests from :

http anything.example.org to https example.org

https anything.example.org to https example.org

But there is a problem that I cannot solve

http example.org to https example.org

Can you help me to find out the tricky part (I think server_name part)

```
server {
  error_log /opt/domain/web/logs/error.log;
  access_log /opt/domain/web/logs/access.log;
  root /opt/domain/web/html;
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name *.example.org example.org;
  return 301 https://example.org$request_uri;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
  error_log /opt/domain/web/logs/error.log;
  access_log /opt/domain/web/logs/access.log;
  root /opt/domain/web/html;
  autoindex on;
  autoindex_exact_size off;

  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.org;
  auth_basic “Administrator Area”;
  auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to split your first `server` block in two:

```
server {
  error_log /opt/domain/web/logs/error.log;
  access_log /opt/domain/web/logs/access.log;
  listen 80;
  server_name *.example.org example.org;
  return 301 https://example.org$request_uri;
}

server {
  error_log /opt/domain/web/logs/error.log;
  access_log /opt/domain/web/logs/access.log;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name *.example.org;
  return 301 https://example.org$request_uri;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```